# "Arigatō" and "gozaimasu" combined into a single word?

Tags: words, phonetics, spoken-language

In Japan for three years, and I've noticed that the locals often sound like they're combining the two words "arigatō" and "gozaimasu" into a single word, "arigatōzaimasu".

Am I hearing things (possible, as they speak very quickly), or is this a common practice?

Comment: You mean "arigatōzaimasu" as opposed to "arigatōgozaimasu", right?

Comment: @taylor That's correct.

Comment: there is even あざ～す!

Comment: @user1205935 does the shortened version follow the "melody"(for lack of a better word) of ありがとうございます?

Comment: @Flaw Yeah, sure, it follows the "melody" ;) I looked, but couldn't find a sound sample, sorry.

Comment: @Flaw Found one! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bu96t6g9NNs Click on 0:17.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility is that the /g/ is being lenited into a voiced velar fricative /ɣ/, as is common between vowels in Japanese. (See ["Handbook of the International Phonetic Association: Japanese" by Hideo Okada](http://archive.org/details/rosettaproject_jpn_phon-2), or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Japanese_phonology&oldid=506661712#Weakening).) Further, since the second /g/ has rounded vowels (/o/) on both sides, it is likely to be somewhat rounded (/ɣʷ/ = /w̝/).

The utterance, phonemically

> /aɽígatoogozaimásu/

then would be something like

> [àɽíɣàtoow̝ozaimás]

Judging by your username, I'm guessing you're a native English speaker. Since most varieties of English diphthongize /o/ to something like /ow/, and minimally distinguish vowel length, English speakers are likely less sensitive to the intervening [w̝] and to the extra-long vowel sequence /ooo/. So you hear the utterance as

> /arigatoːzaimas/

which would be transcribed as "arigatōzaimasu".

Comment: Your assumption on my native tongue is correct, and that is one very fine and in-depth answer.

Comment: The lenition to [ɣ] was what I had guessed as well. Good explanation!

Comment: Does this rule out the possibility of an underlying morphological process? How do we know that /aɽígatoogozaimásu/ is or is not a derived compound?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're just hearing two words that get said quickly and become slurred because they're so commonly used together. Human beings are lazy like that. I would think that "thank you" sounds like one word to a non-native English speaker :)

Comment: True enough, and again, they _do_ speak their language quite quickly.

Comment: Actually 39 (san-kyuu) is e-mail Japanese for thank you because that's how  people say it to each other.

Comment: @Tim: Ah yes, sorry, I meant "as spoken by a native English-speaker" ;)